# Modify one to many relationship in Django

Tags: django

I have two models in a one to one relationship:

```
class GPSDevice(models.Model):
    device_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

```
class SessionGPS(models.Model):
   
    start= models.IntegerField()
    end= models.IntegerField()
    gps_device = models.OneToOneField(GPSDevice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sesion_gps_device")
```

I realized I have a mistake, a GPSDevice can have many SessionGPS. The problem is that to correct this I should delete the one to one relation in SessionGPS and add a ForeignKey field in GPSDevice:

```
class GPSDevice(models.Model):
    device_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    session_gps = models.ForeignKey(SessionGPS, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sesion_gps") #added
```

```
class SessionGPS(models.Model):
    foco = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    inicio_sesion = models.IntegerField()
    fin_sesion = models.IntegerField()
    #gps_device = models.OneToOneField(GPSDevice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="sesion_gps_device")  deleted
```

I have already data in the database and I fear that migrating this can produce a mess in the database as have happened before to me.

Is there another way, like doing something in the SessionGPS model?

Comment: If a GPSDevice can have many related SessionGPS then the foreign key should be defined on SessionGPS, in which case the migration may be simple as the same column can be used

Comment: I got confused. It worked, thanks.